# Set foreign key check = 0 in PHP for deletion

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am attempting to delete from a table that connects to another through the use of Foreign keys, when I delete the user, I want the associated data in another table to delete also. However I am always receiving an error. I have the code to delete a user:

```
  public function delete_user($id){

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SET foreign_key_checks=0");

     $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:id");
     $stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
     $stmt->execute();
     return $stmt;

   }
```

If a user has created no files, they will be deleted as they are not connected to another table. But if a user has created a file, I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete
>   or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`freshburst`.`tbl_documents`, CONSTRAINT `tbl_users_userID_fk`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `tbl_users` (`userID`))' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\IP3-GROUP13\class.user.php:198 Stack trace:
>
> ```
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\IP3-GROUP13\class.user.php(198): PDOStatement->execute()
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\IP3-GROUP13\deleteUser.php(19): USER->delete_user('3')
> #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\IP3-GROUP13\class.user.php on line 198
> ```

Freshburst is the name of the database, tbl_users contains the user information and tbl_documents contains the documents they have created.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `execute` the sql? The first one! And by the way only prepare what needs bounded vars else there is no need to prepare a sql statment, just `query` it

Comment: Check your foreign key constraint in the related table(s) - it should be `ON DELETE CASCADE`